# REST API Error code after POSTing resource with invalid FK

Tags: rest, restful-url, api-design

I'm designing a REST API which has a `Banner` resource that's related to another two resources: `Placeholder` and `Page`.

While the relationship with `Placeholder` can be `null`, a `Banner` must be related to a `Page`. The business rules define that Pages are always created independently. Then, for new `Banner` resources, the page does always exist and the page's id can be passed as a parameter. The same applies for the `Placeholder`, although this could `null`.

So, I decided that a `Banner` resource can be also created independently (instead of a nested resource) as follows:

```
POST https://api.example.com/banners
{
  "name": "banner's name",
  "page": "PAGE_ID",
  "placeholder": "PLACEHOLDER_ID",

  ... other parameters
}
```

**What error code should be returned by the API when provided `page` or `placeholder` does not exist?**

I'm returning a HTTP 404, but it feels odd. I thought about 409, but this doesn't look like a conflict.

PD: If I used a nested URL as `POST /pages/<page_id>/banners`, the 404 makes sense for a non existent `page`, but it still have the same problem for `placeholder`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin This may be considered as duplicate when passing the parameters in form of the post request body but not when using  `POST /pages/page_id/banners`.  And whether you use the one or other depends how you want to access the resources. So this is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @andih I read the question one more time and I still see it as a duplicate.  The OP is concerned about the IDs sent in the request body. For the ones sent in the URL, a `404` will do the job as the OP mentioned in question.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin only as long as you take first idea of the banners resource as fixed / given. The author seems to be unsure whether this is the correct form because he proposed a second way. For the second approach he does not really know how to deal with the placeholder. One could also explain why to use the one or other approach and how to add the placeholder to the second one, ....

Comment: @andih from @CássioMazzochiMolin's answer in the other post, I conclude that when using `POST /pages/<page_id>/banners`, if the `page_id` doesn't exist, a 404 would be returned, whereas, if the page's is ok, but `placeholder` doesn't, a 422 would be returned. Do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: I'm reopening the question, but it should be the way to go. What stops you from following this approach?

Comment: nothing, I like it. Just wondering if @andih had an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to create a banner resource using `POST /banners` and that banner resource has

- a required `page` attribute which value must be an existing PAGE_ID
- an optional `placeholder` attribute which value must be an existing PLACEHOLDER_ID
- **and a name and other properties** *which I assume must also be controlled*

**Returning a 404 on post /banners is not a good idea**

The consumer may provide from none to all invalid properties. Following your idea that would give something like that:

- If only `page` is invalid you would return a 404
- If only `placeholder` is invalid you would return a 404
- If `page` and `placeholder` are both invalid you would have to return a 404 indicating that both value are invalid
- If other properties are invalid, you would probably return a 400 Bad Request.
- If `page` and/or `placeholder` and some other properties are invalid, which status return? a 404 or 400?

It's a bit complex and inconsistent and therefore not really usable for the API's consumer.

**A 400 Bad Request is a better solution for post /banners**

The best way to handle this use case is to consider all possible errors in the provided resources as a basic `Client Error` and therefore use `400 Bad Request` status. The body of the response will contain a description of each error for each invalid property.

**But there's a cleaner solution with POST /pages/page_id/placeholders/placeholder_id/banners**

The `POST /pages/<page_id>/banners` is almost a good idea, you only need to push it further.

It seems that a `banner` goes into a `placeholder` which is in a `page`. If it's true you can do a `POST /pages/<page_id>/placeholders/<placeholder_id>/banners` to create a banner.

- If `page_id` is invalid you return a 404 (indicating 'page not found')
- If `page_id` is valid but `placeholder_id` is invalid you return a 404 (indicating 'place holder not found')
- If `page_id` and `placeholder_id` are valid but property in the banner is invalid you return a 400 Bad Request (indicating which values are invalid)